# Java: how can I avoid GC aka stop the world event?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Lets say I am reading a single incoming stream with millions of transaction per ms, is so fast that I can't afford to have a GC or the entire system will hang.

The functionality is very simple, it is merely to record every single packets that went pass NIC card. (hypothetical)

Is it even possible? 
Are there design pattern for such implementation? I only know flyweight and resource pool design pattern.
Do I really need to code in C so that I can manage it?

1) I can have reasonable amount of ram but not ridiculous like 100gb (maybe 16gb)?
2) CPU processing is not an issue.

FAQ:

Must it be Java? No, please recommend me another language that can support most platform. (linux, aix, windows)

Comment: Use a JVM that doesn't do "stop the world".

Comment: Millions of transactions per millisecond? You're screwed. The trick is to not create anything that needs collecting. I'm not sure Java is the language for the task you describe, though.

Comment: If you have millions of transactions per second, you're kind of working in real-time territory. Perhaps you need a second service to cache things while your JVM is paused. You can minimize "stop the world" by tuning, but you cannot eliminate it entirely, and especially in the scenario you're dealing with. Have you thought of using a different language? Perhaps something that is more system-level?

Comment: Millions of Transactions per ms = less than a nanosecond per transaction. Unrealistic

Comment: If you want to capture every packet that goes through a NIC, then Java is certainly the wrong language -- it doesn't give you any way to directly access the NIC. Is this your *real* problem or hypothetical?

Comment: Are you sure Java is right choice of technology for what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am not sure that is why I am asking.

Comment: You'll have to write/modify a network device driver. That's C and Assembly. see http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000080.do

Answer (score 1):

1. If you really want to handle everything passing through your network card. Java is the wrong language. Look into C possibly C++ or Assembler.
2. As you have been told a million transactions per milliseconds seem unrealistic, only achievable when you are able to split the work between multiple (read many many many) computers
3. There are many Garbage Collectors out there, go do some searching if anything is good for you.
4. If you really don't want the garbage collector to kick in, I think your only option is: Don't create garbage. Initialize an array of bytes as your memory to work in. Only use primitives, no Objects. It will be cumbersome, but it might be fast and I have been told this is the kind of stuff people working on real time systems do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant millions of transactions per second, not ms, you can use [Chronicle](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Chronicle/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md) which promises up to 5-20m transactions per second, persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that millions of transactions per milliseconds is a joke or a hyperbole. No single computer can handle that much, particularly if a mere 100Gb counts as ridiculous amounts of RAM.

But ignoring the actual number of expected transactions, what is needed for this type of task is [real-time Java](http://www.rtsj.org/). Provided that you want to stick with Java.

Either way you'll probably need a real-time OS first, because your application isn't going to be the only thing running on the computer and if the OS decides not to give your application control when it needs it, there's nothing you can do.

**Update:** If you only want to capture network traffic, don't reinvent the wheel, use [`libpcap`.](http://www.tcpdump.org/). AFAIK there's even a Java wrapper to it.

Comment: if i don't want to stick with Java.. what other language should I look at? C? ADA?

Comment: As I said, if the task is what you're saying it is, you don't need any language at all: libpcap does that job already.

Comment: Sadly that is not the task I am looking at, is for a proprietary system.

Comment: In that case the question is too broad.